# How to get a bootlog when I cannot boot into Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtual-machine

Here's my puzzle: I cannot boot my Windows 7 VM -- it gets stuck on the startup screen with the pretty pulsing windows icon.  I can get into safemode ok.  I believe if I could only get to the bootlog for the normal startup that I could figure out what's preventing startup.

Now, whenever I reset I get to the menu with the several safemode options, last known configuration, or start windows normally.

[image]

But none of them have the option to bootlog like for example XP did.

So I found that I could go into safemode and use msconfig.exe to turn Boot logging on (see http://windows7themes.net/enable-boot-logging-in-windows-7.html).

*However*, the trouble is that if I then restart windows normally, I presume it creates the bootlog.  But then the only way I can view it is to start into safemode.  And after starting safemode the bootlog is for the safemode startup, not for the previous normal startup.

How can I get a bootlog created for the normal startup, and then actually view it?

Comment: VM is VirtualBox running in OSX 10.6.8.  Windows 7 is reasonably up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Hit F8 to get bootlogging, not F5.